# Qt 5.15.2 installation issue on Centos 8

Tags: qt, qt5, centos8

I downloaded `qt-unified-linux-x64-4.2.0-online.run` and installed Qt 5.15.2 on Centos 8.

Qt 5.15.2 with Qt Creator got installed at my home directory.

On running QtCreator, it throws below error

```
Cannot update Qt version information: /home/kd/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake cannot be run.
Cannot update Qt version information: /home/kd/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/qmake cannot be run.
Cannot update Qt version information: /home/kd/Qt/5.15.2/android/bin/qmake cannot be run.
```

Then I checked the permissions of `qmake` and found those correct.

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kd kd 27010672 Nov  6  2020 /home/kd/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

Additional, all above qmake runs well when executed separately on terminal.

The problem is QtCreator starts but unable to auto-detect kits. Can you provide valuable inputs?

Comment: I found a workaround. Installed `qt-base`, `qt-creator` from EPEL repo. Then starting `qtcreator` from terminal. And it worked.